# Fortran-- reading columns with specific time stamps

Tags: fortran

I have this data set and I would like to read it using Fortran and apply a few operations . I have presented the data set below. Here's a short description of the data set. The data set starts of with  a time stamp and the subsequent lines (around 60 or 120)are the data points recorded at that time, which is again followed by a time stamp and data and so on so forth. Each file has around 30 observations with 15 different time stamps(i.e two adjacent observations have the same time stamps). I now want to read this file and perform operations such as addition or subtraction of columns on the data points with the same time stamps.

Here the '6:31: 5', '6:27: 9' are the time stamps followed by the data.

Please help as I am unable to figure out a way to do this.
Thank you very much.

[image: Here the '6:31: 5' is the time stamp followed by the data]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is very broad. I can't think how a good answer could look like. How do your data structures that you want to fill with the data look like? Some kind of arrays? Hard to suggest anything when we don't know what do the data points mean and how they should be grouped. Do you have some code you tried? Is your problem in reading or in the computations?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to read it into a program where in reads the intial character string(Time stamp is character) and then red all the lines of data below it until it reaches the other time stamp character. Now I want to compare the previous time stamp value and the current one and if they match I would like to read the column data below the timestamp and +/-  the two columns. I have a have a huge code butthe routiines I have tried are kinda messed up. using the previous on I have managed this output.

Comment: And on the question about what this data is --- it is the value of the y axis part of a graph.

Answer (score 1):

Your question leaves a lot of ambiguity. The way I understand it is that you want to read a file where the contents of a line might be one of two different things: a value, or a time stamp.

And you don't know which one it is before you read it.

The best way, I think, is to first read the line into a string.

```
character(len=20) :: line
read(1001, '(A)') line
```

Then, based on the first character in that string, you can deduce which one it is.

```
if (line(1:1) == "'") then
    ! It's a time stamp
else
    ! It's a new value
end if
```

If it's a value, you can read it straight out of the line variable:

```
read(line, *) val
```

Reading the time stamp is more complicated, because I don't quite know where the colons are inside it. If the hours are all single digits, you could get away with something like this:

```
read(line, '(X, I1, X, I2, X, I2)') hour, minute, second
```

But because there are hours that can't be written with a single digit, I rather doubt that.

So I suggest that you create a subroutine that uses the [`INDEX`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/INDEX-intrinsic.html) function to locate the colons, and then slice the line to read each value separately.

```
hm = index(line, ':', back=.FALSE.) ! hour-minute separator
ms = index(line, ':', back=.TRUE.)  ! minute-second separator
read(line(2:hm-1), *) hour
read(line(hm+1:ms-1), *) minute
read(line(ms+1:), *) second
```

All put together:

```
program timestamp
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: runit = 1001
    integer :: io_err
    character(len=20) :: line
    real :: val
    integer :: hour, minute, second

    open(unit=runit, file='data.txt', action='READ', status='OLD', iostat=io_err)
    if (io_err /= 0) then
        write(*, *) "Unable to open file"
        stop 1
    end if

    do
        read(runit, '(A)', iostat=io_err) line
        if (io_err == -1) then
            write(*, *) "End of file"
            exit
        end if
        if (line(1:1) == "'") then
            call read_timestamp(line, hour, minute, second)
            write(*, '(A, 2(I2.2, ":"), I2.2)') "New timestamp: ", hour, minute, second
        else
            read(line, *) val
            write(*, *) "Data: ", val
        end if
    end do
    close(runit)

contains

    subroutine read_timestamp(line, hour, minute, second)
        implicit none
        character(len=*), intent(in) :: line
        integer, intent(out) :: hour, minute, second
        integer :: hm, ms ! Indices of separators
        hm = index(line, ':', back=.FALSE.)
        ms = index(line, ':', back=.TRUE.)
        read(line(2:hm-1), *) hour
        read(line(hm+1:ms-1), *) minute
        read(line(ms+1:), *) second
        return
    end subroutine read_timestamp
end program timestamp
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I am sorry if my post was a ambiguous. I will try to explain better now. Using the subroutine timestamp The loop i think works this way... read timestamp-> read data->read timestamp->read data... so on so forth. Now what I want to dso is read the first timestamp and the data following it. So when it come to execute the loop the second time it should compare the second time stamp with the first and if they match then read or else skip. after this it read the third timestamp, compares it to the second one and not the first one and reads if they match else skip.

Comment: like this... read timestamp 1--> read data --> read timestamp 2-->comapre with timestamp 1-->if(equal)>>read data <<else(skip) -->read timestamp 3 --> compare with timestamp2--> if(equal)>>read data <<else(skip)-->read timestamp 4 --> compare with timestamp3....so on